# dynamic rendering based on data results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am curious if this is even possible.  I am looking to render data based on the results of an action in ruby on rails.  Here is the code:

```
def convert
  render :text => Item.convert(params[:file], params[:output])
end
```

As you can see currently it just renders text.  The item model takes in two parameters:  a file and output.  The output could be xml, json, plain text, etc.  Some type of data.  What I was hoping I could do is that I could render the output based on the output parameter.  But make it dynamic.  I was hoping I could do:

```
def convert
  @items = Item.convert(params[:file], params[:output])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @items }
    format.xml { render :xml => @items }
  end
end
```

Something that would call the method and based on the data returned it would render the appropriate data.  Testing the above code returns an empty page.  The body tag is completely empty.

Any ideas?

thanks
Mike Riley

Comment: Just one question before answering - *Did you create your routes using  resources* ?

Comment: I did not.  Just doing post 'product/convert' => 'product#convert', as: :convert_products.

Comment: No Issue. Can you give the output of `rake routes` ?

Comment: how `format.json` or `format.whatever` works is that it checks the request to see the headers of the request to know what to render, see [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters)

Comment: rake routes:  convert_items POST /item/convert(.:format) item#convert
           root      /                         item#index

Comment: thanks bjhaid, will take a look.  I had read it over, but must have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying on the name of `params[:output]` to determine what to render, I would write is as below:

```
def convert
  @items = Item.convert(params[:file], params[:output])
  if File.extname(params[:output].match("text"))
    render :text => Item.convert(params[:file], params[:output])
  elsif File.extname(params[:output].match("json"))
    render :json => Item.convert(params[:file], params[:output])
  elsif File.extname(params[:output].match("xml"))
    render :xml => Item.convert(params[:file], params[:output])
  else
    render :html => "default_html"
  end
end
```

and you should have a `default_html.html.erb` that you would render if the extension name of the file does not match what is expected